# PHP - Finding consecutive values in multidimensional associative arrays for seat reservation program

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm working on a program to reserve seats for a show. I have a multidimensional array that is created using $row and $column variables. After making a few initial reservations, I need to pass integers into a function/some code to make further reservations.

I've tried looping through the array to find consecutive available seats (value "avail") but it ignores reserved seats or skips over them. I'll need to later use manhattan distance to reserve the best seats (from row 1, seat 6) first.

function to create the array:

```
//function to create seating chart data structure
function createChart($row, $column){
    //create array for row values
    $row_chart = array();
    for($r=0; $r < $row; $r++){
        $row_number = $r + 1;
        $row_chart[$row_number] = array(); // array of cells for row $r
    }
    //create array for column values
    $column_chart = array();
        for($c=0; $c < $column; $c++){
            $column_number = $c + 1;
            //$location = $c_num;
            $status = "avail";
            foreach($row_chart as $key => $value){
                $column_chart[$column_number] = $status; //add arrays of "seats" for each row
            }
        }

    //nest the column array into the row array
    foreach($row_chart as $key => $value){
        foreach($column_chart as $k => $v){
            $seating_chart[$key][$k] = $status; 
        }
    }
    //$seating_chart = array_combine($row_chart, $column_chart);
    return $seating_chart;
}
```

function to make initial reservations:

```
    $initial_reservation = "R1C4 R1C6 R2C3 R2C7 R3C9 R3C10";
    $initial_reservation = explode(" ", $initial_reservation);
    echo "<br> <br>";
    print_r($initial_reservation);
    $initial_res_length = count($initial_reservation);
    echo "<br> <br>";
    //echo $initial_res_length;

    //split each seat up into integers to mark it reserved in the array
//issue for flexibility: find way to break up string by letters and numbers for larger charts
    for($a = 0; $a < $initial_res_length; $a++){
        $reso_row = substr($initial_reservation[$a], 1, 1);
        //echo $reso_row . "<br>";    
        $reso_column = substr($initial_reservation[$a], 3, 2);
        //echo $reso_column . "<br>";
        $working_chart[$reso_row][$reso_column] = "reserved";
    }

    //echo "<br> <br>";
    //echo "<pre>" . print_r($working_chart, 1) . "</pre>";
```

what I have so far in attempt to make further reservations:

```
//write some code to find consecutive seats
    $seats_needed = 4;
    $outer_array_length = count($working_chart);
    //echo $outer_array_length;

    for($d = 1; $d < $outer_array_length + 1; $d++){
        for($e = 1; $e < $seats_needed + 1; $e++){
            //issue: run through $seats_needed amount of times and executes the code block
            //needed: check if $seats_needed amount of seats in available first then run reservation code
                if($working_chart[$d][$e] === "avail"){
                    $working_chart[$d][$e] = "new reservation";  
                }
                else{
                    echo "Sorry, not possible.";
                }

        }
        break;
    }

    echo "<br> <br>";
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($working_chart, 1) . "</pre>";
```

I'd like to be able to find a number of available seats ($seats_needed) first, and then loop through to reserve them.

Comment: your function createChart($row, $column) returns exactly the same as `array_fill(1, $row, array_fill(1,  $column, "avail"))`

Comment: Thanks for this as well, I was thinking about whether I could do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have initialized the $working_chart with :

```
$working_chart =  createChart(10, 11);
```

I have written the attempt to make further reservations :

```
foreach(array_keys($working_chart) as $d ){
    $maxColumn = count($working_chart[$d]) - $seats_needed + 1;
    for($e = 1; $e <= $maxColumn ; $e++){
        if(["avail"] === array_unique(array_slice($working_chart[$d], $e - 1 , $seats_needed))){
            $working_chart[$d] = array_replace($working_chart[$d], array_fill($e, $seats_needed, "new reservation"));
            break 2;
        }
        else{
            echo "Sorry, not possible.";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you...

Comment: Thank you! This helped.